# PHP function gives 2 differents results

Tags: php, date, while-loop

I have a code that shows the days of a month and return the day number.

But I have a problem

```
function getDays($annee = null, $mois, $jour){
  if(empty($annee)){
    $annee = date('Y');
  }
  $date = new DateTime('first '.$jour.' of '.$mois.' '.$annee);
  $thisMonth = $date->format('m');
  $ok = array();

  while ($date->format('m') === $thisMonth) {
      echo $date->format('d');
      $date->modify('next '.$jour);
      array_push($ok, $date->format('d'));
  }
  return $ok;

}
```

At this line : `echo $date->format('d');`

there are : `01 08 15 22 29`

But when I : `var_dump(getDays('2018','jan','mon'));`

There are : `08 15 22 29 05`

So I was wondering, how could this give me two differents results ?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be pushing to the array before you modify the date?

Comment: Damn you are right !

Comment: `array_push` is still a thing.. :-/ who knew.  I just do `$array[] = $data`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Devon

```
function getDays($annee = null, $mois, $jour){
  if(empty($annee)){
    $annee = date('Y');
  }
  $date = new DateTime('first '.$jour.' of '.$mois.' '.$annee);
  $thisMonth = $date->format('m');
  $ok = array();

  while ($date->format('m') === $thisMonth) {
      echo $date->format('d');
      array_push($ok, $date->format('d'));
      $date->modify('next '.$jour);
  }
  return $ok;

}
```

I moved up the push_array line and it works !